# Can I delete specific files & folders from the local copy of git repo. & commit/push the code? Everything is done in NetBeans IDE & not from terminal

Tags: git, netbeans, version-control, git-push, git-commit

I'm a **PHP** developer by profession and I'm a newbie to this thing **Git**.

Also I've **No Idea** at all about using **Git** from the **Terminal** using **Git commands**.

Whatever knowledge I have to use **Git** is using the **NetBeans IDE** only.

I've been given a local machine running on **Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS**. It already has installed **NetBeans IDE 8.0**. This **NetBeans IDE** has **Git plugin** already installed.

I've been asked to remove specific files and folders from the repository branch on **Git server**.

So, I made a clone of the git branch on my local Ubuntu machine which I asked to manipulate using menu **Team-->Git-->Clone** and by providing necessary details like Git Repo URL, Username, Password.

Now tell me if I select the specific files and folders from the clone and delete them using the delete option present in **NetBeans IDE** and commit/push the code base will the same set of files and folders will get removed from the **Git branch** present on **Git server** too?

If yes I'll proceed with that way. If no then please provide me the way to do it.

Please guide me in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you delete a file or a folder on your local git repository and then you add, commit and push the changes to a remote server, it will update that branche's history on the remote too.

Answer (score 0):

No, not for me.

To do it, in the **Projects** tab, right click on the project's **Source Files** and then select **Git** and **Show Changes**.
When the deleted files appear, select the files you want to delete, right click, and there you can **Commit**...